# Multiple AVAudioPlayers - No Sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I'm fairly new Xcode and ObjC and I'm having trouble playing multiple audio files through multiple AVAudioPlayers.

In theory my app is fairly simple, it takes a cars RPM and Load values and plays a sound based on those values.

So, I have 13 sound samples for a range of RPM values. My code figures out what volume and rate they should be played at to replicate the correct engine sounds in the app - note they are all playing at the same time, it's the volume and rate that controls how they sound.

So, I figure out the volumes and rates like this (this is a snippet) :

```
if ((rpm > 4989) && (rpm < 5339)) {

    av1Pitch  = 0.0f;
    av2Pitch  = 0.0f;
    av3Pitch  = 0.0f;
    av4Pitch  = 0.0f;
    av5Pitch  = 0.0f;
    av6Pitch  = 0.0f;
    av7Pitch  = 0.0f;
    av8Pitch  = 0.0f;
    av9Pitch = rpm / 4989.0f;
    av10Pitch = rpm / 5338.0f;
    av11Pitch  = 0.0f;
    av12Pitch  = 0.0f;
    av13Pitch  = 0.0f;

    av1Volume  = 0.0f;
    av2Volume  = 0.0f;
    av3Volume  = 0.0f;
    av4Volume  = 0.0f;
    av5Volume  = 0.0f;
    av6Volume  = 0.0f;
    av7Volume  = 0.0f;
    av8Volume  = 0.0f;
    av9Volume = av9Pitch - 1.0f;
    av10Volume = 1.0f - av9Volume;
    av11Volume  = 0.0f;
    av12Volume  = 0.0f;
    av13Volume  = 0.0f;
}
```

Then I go through 13 AVAudioPlayers and set the players volume and rate :

```
if (audioPlayer2000.isPlaying) {
    //already playing, ready for volume / pitch adjustments

    audioPlayer2000.volume = av2Volume;
    audioPlayer2000.rate = av2Pitch;   
}
else{
    //nothing playing - play the file
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/1052.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSError *error;
    //NSData *songFile2 = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&error];
    audioPlayer2000 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
    //audioPlayer2000 = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:songFile2 error:&error];
    audioPlayer2000.numberOfLoops = -1;
    audioPlayer2000.enableRate = YES;
    audioPlayer2000.rate = av2Pitch;
    audioPlayer2000.volume = av2Volume;

    if (audioPlayer2000 == nil) {
        NSLog([error description]);
    }
    else{
        [audioPlayer2000 play];
    }   
}
```

This works OK whilst it is playing 1 file, but as soon as I change the RPM value so that it should be playing another file, all of the sounds stop no matter what the RPM value is.

The only way I've found to stop this is to call setCurrentTime on the players - but this results in a 'jittery' playback.

I thought it might be ARC playing up, so I created properties for all the players.

Am I missing something fundamental here? Or am I not taking the right approach?

Comment: what value you are getting in av2Volume ? check that

Comment: Can't really tell what is wrong here although `av9Pitch - 1.0f` seems a strange volume.  For something like this I would have thought that OpenAL would be the way to go, but I don't know of a reason why AVAudioPlayer wouldn't work.

Comment: If I put a breakpoint in at av2Volume I can see that it is getting a valid value (0.899884 for example).
Thanks for the OpenAL tip, I'll take a look into it.

Comment: OK I think figured it out - setting the volume to 0.0f must stop the audio somehow - setting it to 0.01f seems to work fine! Weird!